# Correlation bound proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

**Disclaimer:** I am not talking about the correlation coefficient $\rho \in [-1,1]$

The correlation, according to a textbook I have, is defined as $m_{11} = E[XY]$ given the Model $(X,Y,f(x,y))$ of $2$ random variables $X$, $Y$.

I want to prove that $$\frac{m_{11}^2}{E[X^2] - E[Y^2]} \leq 1.$$

I tried $E[(aX \pm Y)^2] \geq 0$, which led me to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$(E[XY])^2 \leq E[X^2]E[Y^2].$$ I don’t know if the textbook is wrong, however if it holds, then by symmetry this should also hold:
$$\frac{m_{11}^2}{E[Y^2] - E[X^2]} \leq 1.$$

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**Correction:** I had misread the denominator previously. Now it is fixed.

Comment: What textbook are you referring to?

Comment: It’s in Greek: Analysis of Stohastic Signals by Stavros Panas.

Comment: This cannot be right as written; consider $X$ mean zero, variance 1, and $Y=X$. See a problem?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Ok I am not saying it is correct, however when we write in the denominator $E[X^2]-E[Y^2]$ we are assuming that this does not equal zero. With Y = X we have a problem it equals 0. So we are examining cases where the denominator is nonzero.

Comment: I tried Y = aX and again there is a problem. It may hold under special conditions for specific random variables. But one counter example is enough. Thanks for helping me realize it!

Comment: @Anonymous It should be clear that it doesn't work with the counterexample I mentioned; write the inequality as $m_{11}^2\leq E[X^2]-E[Y^2]$ if you are worried about division by zero. I'll give you another counterexample (in fact, here are infinitely many): Let $Y=kX$ for $k^2\in (1/2,1).$ Either your textbook is wrong or you misinterpreted it.

Comment: ^for $X$ mean zero and var 1

Comment: of course, no prob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not always true. Let's take $X$, $Y$ such that $P (X = 2) = 1$ and $P (Y = 1) = 1$. Then it becomes false ($4/3\leq 1$).